# Why isn't page attributes dropdown not showing up in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

After successfully creating a custom post type called events, I created a new template file to choose when creating event custom type page. But in the edit screen, there is no Page Attributes dropdown option to choose the newly created template.

How do I get the dropdown to be visible?

[image]

Comment: How did you create the template file? Did you set the post type for the template?

Comment: I created a template file by copying original index.php and named it as template-event.php.

Comment: Did you specify a post type like this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jacob. This helped.

Comment: Jacob, please convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Dear Jacob, could you please share your Skype/email id for me to connect with you?